# Equivalent for deprecated select_() and mutate_()

Tags: r, function, select, dplyr

Equivalent for deprecated select_() and mutate_()

I am trying to make a function with this data and would really appreciate your help!

Imagine I have a data.frame like this one (the fusion of control and sites).

I want to select the InitDryW and FinalDryW columns of the Treatment “Control” and then calculate the average.
Inside the function I must write select_() and then mutate_(). However, I understand that these two functions are deprecated.

```
control <- data.frame(Day=c(0,0,0,0,0,0),
              Replica=c(1,1,1,1,1,1),
              Initial_Dry_Weight=c(5.010,5.010,5.010,5.010,5.010,5.000),
              Final_Dry_Weight=c(4.990,4.940,4.840,4.820,4.960,4.970),
              InitiaFraction=c(1.1071,1.1964,1.0647,1.0005,1.0453,1.1212),
              FinalFraction=c(0.3858,0.3504,0.4248,0.3333,0.3417,0.3467),
              Treatment=c("Control","Control","Control","Control","Control","Control"))
control
sites <-data.frame(Day=c(2,4,8,16,32,44),
               Replica=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3),
               Initial_Dry_Weight=c(5.000,5.000,5.000,5.000,5.01,5.000,5.000,5.000,
                                    5.000,5.000,5.000,5.01,5.01,5.01,5.000,5.000,5.000,5.000),
               Final_Dry_Weight=c(4.65,4.63,4.67,4.64,4.37,4.37,4.17,3.72,4.12,4,3.99,3.64,
                                  4.26,3.3,3.47,3.7,3.75,3.3),
            InitiaFraction=c(1.0081,1.0972,1.1307,1.0898,1.075,1.0295,1.0956,1.042,1.0876,
             1.006,1.1052,1.0922,1.0472,1.0843,1.0177,1.0143,1.1112,1.0061),
            FinalFraction=c(0.3229,0.3605,0.3304,0.3489,0.3181,0.2948,0.4098,0.3762,0.3787,
            0.3345,0.3595,0.3511,0.3921,0.3908,0.3385,0.347,0.3366,0.3318),
            Treatment=c("CC","CC","CC","CC","CC","CC","CC","CC","CC","CC","CC","CC","CC",
                "CC","CC","CC","CC","CC"))
sites
total <- dplyr::bind_rows(control,sites)
total
```

My functions is:

```
manipulation <- function(data,
                     InitDryW,
                     FinalDryW,
                     Treatment,
                     Difference) {control <- data %>% 
filter(Treatment == "Control") %>%
select_(InitDryW,FinalDryW) %>%
mutate_(Difference = lazyeval::interp (~a/b,  a=as.name(FinalDryW),b=as.name(InitDryW)))
meanControl <- mean(control$Difference, na.rm = TRUE)
return (meanControl)
}
manipulation()
```

Then, I run the example:

```
control <- manipulation(data= total,
                    InitDryW = "Initial_Dry_Weight",
                    FinalDryW = "Final_Dry_Weight",
                    Treatment = "Treatment")
control
```

Now, I'm getting warnings like these (for both select_() and mutate_()):

Warning message:
mutate_() is deprecated.
Please use mutate() instead
The 'programming' vignette or the tidyeval book can help you
to program with mutate() : https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org

The result is correct, but the first time that warning appears.

My question is: what is the equivalent of select_() and mutate_() in functions in this case?

I think now select_() is solved using only select()

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass unqouted column names and use `{{}}` to evaluate it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

manipulation <- function(data,InitDryW,FinalDryW,Treatment,Difference) {
   control <- data %>% 
               filter({{Treatment}} == "Control") %>%
               select({{InitDryW}},{{FinalDryW}}) %>%
               mutate(Difference = {{FinalDryW}}/{{InitDryW}})
                 
    meanControl <- mean(control$Difference, na.rm = TRUE)
    return (meanControl)
}


manipulation(data= total,
             InitDryW = Initial_Dry_Weight,
             FinalDryW = Final_Dry_Weight,
             Treatment = Treatment)
```

---

However, based on @27 ϕ 9's comment we think you might want to do :

```
manipulation <- function(data,InitDryW,FinalDryW,Treatment) {
   control <- data %>% 
               filter(Treatment == Treatment) %>%
               select({{InitDryW}},{{FinalDryW}}) %>%
               mutate(Difference = {{FinalDryW}}/{{InitDryW}})

    meanControl <- mean(control$Difference, na.rm = TRUE)
    return (meanControl)
}


manipulation(data= total,
             InitDryW = Initial_Dry_Weight,
             FinalDryW = Final_Dry_Weight,
             Treatment = "Control")
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak. However, now I am having this problem: 
Error in eval (cols [[col]], .data, parent.frame ()):
   object 'Final_Dry_Weight' not found

Comment: @PabloE.Gutierrez-Fonseca are you sure you have copied function correctly and calling it correctly as shown in the answer? Are you using the same data as shared in your post because it works for me using that data.

Answer (score 0):

I think NSE (non standard evaluation) could help you. At first it might be a little bit confusing, but I think it's quite an elegant way to forget about the underscore functions :) All(?) the dplyr functions work somehow that way. So you should already be familiar with the concept (even if you didn't know about it):

... here is an example.

```
# some data
dat <- dplyr::tibble(A=1:5,
                     B=5:1)
# some function
some_function <- function(dat,     
                          .var){   
  .var <- rlang::enquo(.var)
  dat %>%
    dplyr::select(!!.var)
}

# run function
some_function(dat,.var=B)

# output
# A tibble: 5 x 1
B
<int>
1     5
2     4
3     3
4     2
5     1
```